# How can I change screens in same activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am new in Android. I have been trying to make a game. I have many questions and when user reply these, screen will change and show another questions. How can I do it without changing activity? Thanks

I want to change only this part of view in every question when push  the button.

```
 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/typeRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flagPart1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flagPart2"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flagPart3"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Can you please share your code so we can help you out?

Comment: You can change the textview by set text when you want to change the value or CHange its visibility. I think you got answers from other users.

Comment: but I don't want to change only TextView. I want to change TableRow.

Comment: do you want to swap table row or you wanted to change the text on table row?

Comment: I want to change `TableRow` completely

Comment: your requirement is very complicated :(  . Please extend your question. what do you want to change table row record ? or the whole the table row? its really simple If you want to change the whole record in table row you have to change the textfield which is in the table row.

Comment: I have 2 `TableRow` like above. According to data that come from database, one of them will shown and these `TextView`'s(in TableRow) background color will change again according to data. When click the button, view will change. I did it but as I refresh activity every click. Now I want to do this without changing activity. Only change this view :) I hope its achievable. If not I continue changing activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a handle on your TextView by calling `TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtextview)` in your `onCreate()` Method.

You can then use `textView.setText("Your Text here")` to change the value.

If you make the `textView` a class attribute you can change its value from other methods, too. Please keep in mind that you still have to init the variable with the `findViewById` method in your `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep a reference to the `TextView`s you want to fill with data in your `Activity`
2. Fill these `TextView`s with different text

Answer (score 0):

You can use visibilty ..u can hide or show ur view like

1. textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
2. textview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update text in TextViews:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("text");
```

More complex solution to changing UI inside the Activity is [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).